# Listview in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

First of all i am newbie in html,javascript. I'm trying to build a website referring to my android app and construct from scratch a list with custom listview ( mostly for learning and before using javascript libraries like Mootools , Ember and so on). My list:

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

As a listview i use ( as an example ):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input name="num" type="button" class="btn1" id="num" value="1" />
    <div id="from">From: </div>
    <div id="startcity"></div>
    <div id="to">To:</div>
    <div id="finalcity"></div>
</div>
```

Now, I'm trying to create a list including three items:

```
<script>
    for(n=0;n<3;n++){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var er = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
        var qw = li.appendChild(er);
        document.getElementById('list').appendChild(qw);
    }
</script>
```

My intention is to use div 'wrapper' and all its elements as an item view 3 times but on the browser i don't see anything created from loop except from first html 'wrapper'. Any suggestions;

Comment: As it is set up, you will only see 3 times `From : To:` but anythin else because I don't see where you add your information in these tags. A working example would be very useful.

Comment: Adding information from json is a further step. I don;t see not even one list item..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit3:** To hide your div not created from your loop simply wrap your div with another wrapper (that has `display: none;`) like so:

```
<div style="display: none">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <input name="num" type="button" class="btn1" id="num" value="1" />
        <div id="from">From:</div>
        <div id="startcity"></div>
        <div id="to">To:</div>
        <div id="finalcity"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that if you add "display: none" to your actual wrapper then the divs created with your loop won't be displayed. This is because `.cloneNode` also clones the style.

**Edit2:**

You are using `position: absolute;` and setting the position of each of these elements on top of one another. This also shows that you are using the same `id` ***multiple times***... which you should **avoid**. id's should be **unique**.

```
#apo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 39px;
    height: 23px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 126px;
    top: 34px;
}
#startpoli {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 37px;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 213px;
    top: 19px;
    background-color: #98d0d2;
}
#pros {
    position: absolute;
    width: 48px;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 122px;
    top: 74px;
}
#finalpoli {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 37px;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 213px;
    top: 69px;
    background-color: #c6d298;
}
```

**This is the result when I remove some of your css causing the problems:**

[image: remove position absolute]

**Here is the modified css for the image on top:**

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #e5e4e2;
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.btn1{
    background-color: #CAC9DB;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    }
#apo {
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
#startpoli {
}
#apo {

    width: 39px;
    height: 23px;

}
#startpoli {
    width: 200px;
    height: 37px;
    background-color: #98d0d2;
}
#pros {

    width: 48px;
    height: 25px;

}
#finalpoli {

    width: 200px;
    height: 37px;

    background-color: #c6d298;
}
```

**Edit:** It seems that the wrapper doesn't allow itself to be added to multiple elements at the same time. So just clone ( with `.cloneNode(true)` ) the original `er`

`li.appendChild(er)` doesn't return an element last I checked. Just append `li` to your `list` instead of `qw`

```
var er = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
for(var n=0;n<3;n++){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(er.cloneNode(true)); //clone original wrapper and add it to your li
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li); //add li to your list
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kv4Lteza/)

Comment: @ringo where did you put your script? In your head or at the end of your body?

Comment: @ringo check update. I cloned er everytime I wanted to append it.

Comment: @ringo it works fine. I went on your website... it's just that it seems you have a css problem. All 3 wrappers are stacked upon one another. Remove your css  and notice that it does work.

Comment: Why 'from',' startcity' , 'to' , 'finalcity' divs  doesn't show on every list item; Is there a way  to treat with wrapper div as a whole with all its components;

Comment: @ringo they do, but it doesn't seem like you're using my code anymore.

Comment: @ringo... remove all your **position: absolute;** in your css. You are making everything stack on one another that way. Check update.

Comment: Thanks Grimbode. Now it works.Final question: how can i disappear first 'wrapper' not producing from loop;

Comment: Excellent. I have no words...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let see what your code is doing:

```
// loop x3
for(n=0;n<3;n++){

// you create new element LI in li
var li = document.createElement("li");

// you get WRAPPPER instance in er
// what is WRAPPER? you have only one?
var er = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 

// you add er (child) to li (parent), this is what you want?
// qw is nothing, appendchild will return nothing
var qw = li.appendChild(er);

// you add qw (you mean WRAPPER?) to LIST x3 times, maybe you want to do this only 1 time
document.getElementById('list').appendChild(qw);
}
```

now, this should be your solution

```
var er = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
for(n=0;n<3;n++){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  er.appendChild(li);
}
document.getElementById('list').appendChild(er);
```

or, in case you need a wrapper per element

```
for(n=0;n<3;n++){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var wr = document.createElement("div");
  li.appendChild(wr);
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
}
```

or, if wrapper is one and you want to clone it:

```
var er = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
for(n=0;n<3;n++){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(er.cloneNode());
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting one view ( coming from html 'wrapper' ) and nothing on list except from three dots

Comment: You want to see the "wrapper" element multiplied x3 in list?

Comment: Exactly Matteo. 'wrapper' element with all its div components

Comment: You cannot display the same element in multiple location, just one. A possible solution should be clone your node, give me a second